# The file in stash server was reverted to a previous revision without any log

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

We met a problem in git.(We use Atlassian Stash in our team)
    A file named "one.py" was firstly changed at 2015/04/01.
    Then some other developers pushed a lot of changes to server in the coming days.
    Later in 2015/04/08, the "one.py" file was changed again and push to stash server.
    Then some other developers pushed a lot of changes to server as usual.
    And comes the problem, today (2015/04/09), I found that the "one.py" file was reverted to the revision which we pushed the changes in 2015/04/01. And when I checked the "one.py" file's change history, I can't get the change history in 2015/04/08. It lost. 
    What happened? Why we lost the commit history? Can you help me?
Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 1):

Someone rolled back the file version in their local branch and pushed the changes to the server. To figure out who the someone is or which specific commit did this, you can use `git bisect`

This normally happens when someone messes up code merges or uses **revert ** or a similar functionality in any editor tool like TortoiseGIT